# How does a python function variable change value?

Tags: python

In the following function:

```
def f(value,values):
    value = 4
    values[0] = 100
t = 1
v = [1,2,3]
f(t,v)
print(t,v[0])

Output: 1, 100
```

The value of t has not changed but the value of v[0] has changed. Can anybody please explain what is happening?

Comment: State your desired output

Comment: https://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Answer (score 0):

In python, assignment means binding a name to a object. So

```
t = 1
v = [1,2,3]
```

means binding `t` to object integer `1`, binding `v` to object list `[1,2,3]`.
And in function `f(value, values)`, binding new name `value` to the same integer `1` and binding new name `values` to same list `[1,2,3]`. Now we know:

```
         --------                 -----------
t     -> | obj1 |       v      -> |  obj2   |
value -> |   1  |       values -> | [1,2,3] |
         --------                 -----------
```

then statements

```
    value = 4
    values[0] = 100
```

mean that name value is re-binded to object integer `4` (because integer is immutable type, so the object itself cannot be changed), and the first element of object `[1,2,3]` is changed to `100` (list is mutable type).

```
         --------                 -------------
t     -> | obj1 |       v      -> |  obj2     |
         |   1  |       values -> | [100,2,3] |
         --------                 -------------
         --------
value  ->| obj3 |
         |   4  |
         --------
```

So `t` and `v` still bind to original objects, but object list `[1,2,3]` is changed to `[100,2,3]` .

Answer (score 0):

```
def f(value,values):
    value = 4
    values[0] = 100
t = 1
v = [1,2,3]
f(t,v)
print(t,v[0])
```

let start walking through you code, you are defining a function f:

```
def f(value,values):
    value = 4
    values[0] = 100
```

this function takes 2 parameter `value` and `values`, ok  now move to the code after function

```
t = 1         # here you are declaring a variable name 't' and have value 1 
v = [1,2,3]   # here we have 'v' having value [1,2,3] which is a list
f(t,v)        # here you are calling the function 'f' which is declare above
```

Ok, now our main work start when you are calling function 'f' `f(t,v)` with two parameter having value `t=1` & `v=[1,2,3]` when these parameter reaches our function `f(value,values)` we have `value = 1` and `values = [1,2,3]`.

after that, we have `value=4` inside our function so as we have `value = 1` previously then our code will like :

```
value=4  #  previously we have value = 1 so now our code update the value to 4, t does not updated here.
```

after that we have `values[0]=100` so we have values as [1,2,3] this becomes like:

```
values[0]=100 # => [1,2,3][0] = 100 so the array [1,2,3] have 1 on index 0 it will replace 1 in array and now our array becomes [100,2,3]
```

when we do `print(t,v[0])` we have `t=1` and `v[0]=100` because we didn't update the value of t inside our function only the value of our `array [1,2,3]` get update to `[100,2,3]`

Comment: I have edited my answer because there is a mistake, but now this is fine